# OutOfMemoryException when filling List<byte> in C#

Tags: c#

I'm getting an out of memory exception and I don't know why?
This is a my C# code:

```
List<byte> testlist = new List<byte>();
            for (byte i = 0; i <= 255; i++)
            {
                testlist.Add(i); //exception thrown here in the last cycle
            }
```

Comment: Is this a 32-bit process? What is your memory consumption like?

Comment: You should perhaps learn to avoid using `for` loops in `c#`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your loop never terminates because `byte` is an unsigned, 8-bit integer with valid values between 0 and 255.

So, when `i == 255` and the loop body completes, another increment occurs. However, due to the range of `byte`, this does not cause `i` to equal `256` (it can't!), which would in turn cause the loop to terminate.  Instead, it overflows, and rolls around to `0`. So, the loop goes on (and on and on...).  This is a relatively common bug when using unsigned loop counters.

In the meantime, your list is growing until you run OOM.  There's no reason to use a `byte` here; just use `int` and cast `i` when adding it to the list.

Comment: also you (the OP) can use [`checked`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b4xzyw.aspx) to check this ;)

Comment: So this works: List<byte> testlist = new List<byte>();
            for (int i = 0; i <= 255; i++) {
                testlist.Add((byte)i);
            }

Comment: @CarstenKönig Ah, didn't know about `checked`.  Would not want to use it explicitly everywhere though. ;)

Comment: @MickyDuncan of course there is a [global compiler switch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h25wtyxf.aspx) too ;)

Comment: this is super cool. I didnt work it out until I put console.writeline in and wondered why it was taking so long!!

Comment: oh thanks, I didn't knew that for loop makes one more increment :)